# java a stack and queue in a single array

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, queue

> Design a data representation mapping a stack `S` and a queue `Q` into a single array `M`. Write algorithms to add and delete elements from these two data objects.

To make it clear yes is homework!

I'm not asking for an answer I just need a link or something that can guide me to the answer, or if you can give me and example where it can be applied I am new in this and not very good as you can see.

Comment: Do you know how to implements "S" using "M"? Do you know how to implement "Q" using "M"?

Comment: I would start with what you've already got. If you can single out specific questions to ask, then you'll find it a lot easier to get them answered!

Comment: I would search for a similar solution using my favour search tool and start from there. Is there something which this wouldn't help you with?

Comment: the think is that I am so lost on this that I dont even understand the question is it possible for any of you to give me another question with the same idea or something like that?

Comment: If you are so lost you don't understand the question, your teacher is the person you should be talking to. I'm sure you can find a simple solution you can copy/paste if you search the internet, but that would defy the point since you won't understand what the code is doing (or for what purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pretty simple guide will show you the difference between a stack and a queue: http://blog.bakhshi.eu/2005/11/stack-vs-queue.html

Essentially, the data for both a stack and a queue can be stored in an array. The difference is **where** you choose to take a new element out from. For a stack, the next element you take out ('pop') is the last one you put in. For a queue, the next element you take out is the first one you put in.

One approach would be to create a class which has a member variable of an array, and then has some methods:

```
addToQueueOrStack()
popFromQueue()
popFromStack()
```

Comment: @Jiaru makes a good point that I missed, your array will have a fixed size so you need to worry about what happens when it gets full. Perhaps your add method could throw an exception, or (for a basic implementation) just print an error message instead of adding.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know what a stack and queue is. These two data structure have some regular behavior (or operating limitations).

Assume that we want to put our data in a tube. A queue Q is a tube that we put data in on one side, and pop data on the other side; whereas a stack S is a tube that we put and pop data on the same side, and the other side is never accessable.

As your requirement, the given array M is the raw tube where we want to put our data, what we need to do is to add some operating limitations to this tube.

In both queue Q and stack S, we can put our first data at array[0], and the second data follows the previous data putted in at array[1], the third data at array[2], and so on. We always put new data in on one side (like the "tail" of the array). For queue Q, we should pop data different from the side we put data in, so first pop the data at array[0], and then array[1], that is: the place holds data, and have the smallest index of array. For stack S, we should pop data on the same side where we put data in, so first pop the data at "tail", that is: the place holds data, and have the biggest index of array.

The array has a fixed size, so be careful when your data reaches the edge of array. Good luck. ^_^